# java - How to update table status one at a time?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a program in Java that reads the filepath in a table in MySQL and then locates the file and proceeds to do some indexing process to the file.

The table design is like below:

```
UniqueID   FilePath                 Status     
 1          C:\Folder1\abc.pdf       Active
 2          C:\Folder1\def.pdf       Active
 3          C:\Folder1\efg.pdf       Error
```

To keep it simple, it scans through the table for files with status = Active , then locates the file and does indexing process. Once the entire process is completed, the Status is updated to `Complete`.

The problem is I scan every one of them in a resultSet. For example, if `abc.pdf` does not exist, it will update the status to Error and update status of `def.pdf` to Complete.

With my current way of doing, it just updates both of these files to Status Complete and I do not know a way to achieve what I want. Can anyone suggest anything?

Also, let say `doScan()` method throws some error,say file could not be found, then the status should changed to Error for `abc.pdf`
Code:

```
public void doScan_DB() throws Exception {

        try {


            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                String path1 = rs.getString(2);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                updateProcess_DB();

               // call the index function
                Indexing conn = new Indexing();
                conn.doScan(path1);
               updateComplete_DB();






                }


        }catch(SQLException|IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

UpdateProcess:

```
 public void updateProcess_DB(){

  try{



        Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
     statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where STATUS ='Active' ");

  }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();

  }
```

UpdateComplete:

```
public void updateComplete_DB() {

        try {

            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
            statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Complete' where STATUS ='Processing' ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

UpdateError:

```
public void updateError_DB(){

        try{

            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
            statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Error' where STATUS ='Processing' ");

        }catch(Exception e){


            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

EDITED:

CODE:

```
 while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                String path1 = rs.getString(2);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                updateProcess_DB(rs.getString(2));

               // call the index function
                Indexing conn = new Indexing();
                conn.doScan(path1);
               updateComplete_DB(path1);
```

Update method:

```
public void updateProcess_DB(String argument){

  try{



        Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
     statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where STATUS ='Active' ");

  }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();

  }

    }
```

Comment: A little formatting would help us read your code better. Also, did you debug your application?

Comment: Yes, what would I be looking out for?

Comment: You're calling updateProcess_DB() without passing any argument. You didn't post the code of this method, but since it doesn't take any argument, I don't see how it could updates the status of **the** row you're starting to process. So it probably update sthe status of all the rows, which is incorrect.

Comment: I edited my post to include some methods. Perhaps I made a huge mistake where I update all the entire rows instead that meet the constraint?

Comment: Well, you'd be looking for what your code is doing, e.g. how the status is being changed - basically you should get to the conclusion that JB pointed out: `updateProcess_DB()` doesn't take any argument and thus will update _all_ entries that have `status = 'Active'`. If you want to work on them one by one then use their specific id (e.g. the path) instead of the more general status.

Comment: Also, why do you use CONCUR_UPDATABLE if you don't plan to use the ResultSet to update the rows?

Comment: Sorry that was already removed. I forgot to edit it. The latest edit is how it looks now

Comment: @Thomas But I need to update the Status column , not the path

Comment: @Daredevil read my previous comment again, carfully. At each iteration of the loop, you're setting **all** the rows that are Active to "Processing". That's not what you want, right? You want to set the **current** row to "Processing". So your method needs to take the **current** row as argument and to only update the **current** row.

Comment: @JBNizet So it looks something like the above  edited?

Comment: Yes, for example. Except you would need to **use** the argument, to only update the row which has that path. Passing an argument and ignoring it won't wolve your problem.

Comment: @JBNizet In this case, my SQL statement in UpdateProcess_DB still exeuctes if all the status is Active . Shouldn't it affect it?

Comment: You haven't read my comment. Read it. You pass an argument to a method, but the method doesn't do anything with that argument. Don't you realize that this doesn't make sense?

Comment: I posted my solution below, can you give it a quick look.